# PHP foreach loop show category name onces json multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array in which there are three fields substitute name,substitute category and price.
  I have this is on foreach loop. I want to show category name once and under this substitute name.

```
     Array ( 
          [sub1] => 

     Array ( [substitute] => 2 
             [substitute_category] => 7 
             [substitute_price] => 123 ) 

         [sub2] => 

    Array ( 
           [substitute] => 3 
           [substitute_category] => 7 
           [substitute_price] => 139 
          )
         [sub3] =>

 Array ( [substitute] => 4 
         [substitute_category] => 7 
         [substitute_price] => 150 ) 
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

It ain't that hard.

```
echo $category."<br />";
foreach ($array as $sub) {
    echo $sub['substitute_category']."<br />";
}
```

If you already had the foreach, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: $substitute_array = json_decode($rmenu->menu_substitute, true);

foreach ($substitute_array as $value) {  
//print_r($value);


$sub = $value['substitute']; 
$cat_id  = $value['substitute_category']; 
$sub_price = $value['substitute_price']; 
$rest_sub = $this->restaurant_model->getRest_substitute_name($sub);
$rest_menu_category = $this->restaurant_model->getRest_substitute_category($cat_id);


?>


<h2>Choose <?php if (in_array($cat_id, $filteredarray)){ 
    echo $rest_menu_category = $this->restaurant_model->getRest_substitute_category($cat_id);
  }else{
  } 
}